# c++ gui programming resources

Tags: c++, user-interface

I'm entering a Skills USA programming competition where I am unsure of how the contest will go but I do know some rules. The biggest problem is that you aren't allowed to bring any source code. I also heard from a teacher that QT Creator would not be allowed.

If I'm going to be coding in c++ without QT (or any other bundle of libraries) but I have to use something local to windows... what should I do.

There was this bundle of code I found on a website. All it does is create a window, and I would have explored this choice more but look how much code it is...

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

static char sClassName[]  = "MyClass";
static HINSTANCE zhInstance = NULL;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
        WNDCLASSEX WndClass;
        HWND hwnd;
        MSG Msg;

        zhInstance = hInstance;

        WndClass.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        WndClass.style         = NULL;
        WndClass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
        WndClass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
        WndClass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
        WndClass.hInstance     = zhInstance;
        WndClass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        WndClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        WndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
        WndClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
        WndClass.lpszClassName = sClassName;
        WndClass.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

        if(!RegisterClassEx(&WndClass)) {
                MessageBox(0, "Error Registering Class!", "Error!", MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
                return 0;
        }

        hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, sClassName, "db Tutorial", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, 

CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    320, 240, NULL, NULL, zhInstance, NULL);

        if(hwnd == NULL) {
                MessageBox(0, "Error Creating Window!", "Error!", MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
                return 0;
        }

        ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);

        while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
                TranslateMessage(&Msg);
                DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }

        return Msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        switch(Message) {
                case WM_CLOSE:
                        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                        break;
                case WM_DESTROY:
                        PostQuitMessage(0);
                        break;
                default:
                        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I wouldn't have a problem with learning more about this, but since I'm not allowed to bring source code I would have to memorize most of this. That isn't happening.

Are there any ways of creating windows/buttons in c++ that doesn't require me to use something like QT or type up a page of code to create an empty window? I have looked on google and EVERYTHING is about QT creator. Any help would be great.

I'm not looking for the "easy way out", just something that I would be able to remember and type up on the spot without having access to examples besides c++ textbooks.

Comment: Why not use resources? You can then use a resource editor to drag and drop controls.

Comment: @adelphus I'm not sure... I'll include that in an Email I'm going to send to the people in charge of this thing.

Comment: Are you even sure that the projects will use a GUI? If the resources you're allowed are 'C++ textbooks' then I'd expect that you'd be able to find what you need there. I.e. the project will use the standard input and output facilities, rather than require a non-standard GUI. You can get the rules for SkillUSA competitions and check them, and maybe you can find information on projects from past competitions.

Comment: Me think the contest will just be a console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the [web site](http://www.skillsusa.org/compete/contests.shtml) and it says
**Computer Programming**

> Competition consists of project coding and output, a skill-related
>   written test and an interview. The contestants will receive a packet
>   that includes instructions to the written test and each of the two
>   projects. Each project's specifications are written for Visual Basic,
>   Java, C#, C++ and RPG. The projects will be saved on the Desktop in a
>   folder called "SkillsUSA Contestant#_." All projects will be
>   downloaded to a jump drive or diskette (whichever the student prefers)
>   and transferred to a main station to be printed, both code and screen.

It seems that you can any of the mentioned languages. You will be given an assignment or two and will be asked to code it. If any UI is to be included, being a C++ coder you would be at a disadvantage. The VB coders would probably have the easiest time at a UI type assignment.

Comment: thats the thing. I know all three, but honestly if your going to be judging programming skills, the judges will be most impressed with c++. I will not resort to using VB.

Comment: I would hope they would judge you on your ability to choose the correct technology, based upon the task at hand. Square peg, round hole, etc.

Comment: @Gabe the language does not matter as long as the requirements are met below the alloted time.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any ways of creating windows/buttons in c++ that doesn't require me to use something like QT or type up a page of code to create an empty window? I have looked on google and EVERYTHING is about QT creator. Any help would be great.

For an easier way into Windows API level GUI programming, check out my ["Lessons in Windows API Programming"](http://learnwinapi.wordpress.com/), which uses dialog resources to avoid much of the boilerplate code you’re showing.

Still, to create such resources you need tools and documentation.

It sounds like you’re not allowed that, and in that case, if you absolutely have to use C++ and absolutely have to create a GUI, you’re screwed. But I think you must have misunderstood something. One cannot test the skills of a person as a bus driver by requiring the person to drive a bus without any fuel…